# pandas GroupBy level is much slower than GroupBy on column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I notice that pandas groupby on Level is much slower than groupby on columns:

```
t1 = pd.datetime.now()
for name, group in df.groupby(level=['Exchange', 'LongID']):
    name
    group
print(pd.datetime.now() - t1)
```

In [5]: 0:44:07.798892

```
df = df.reset_index()
t1 = pd.datetime.now()
for name, group in df.groupby(by=['Exchange', 'LongID']):
    name
    group
print(pd.datetime.now() - t1)
```

In [5]: 0:00:21.025000

Groupby index is crazy slow. Anyone may know why is that?

**EDIT**
The data is reading from csv, I can't post here, but you could make up some data, and the difference is still there:

```
exchanges = pd.read_excel("https://www.iso20022.org/sites/default/files/ISO10383_MIC/ISO10383_MIC.xls")['MIC'].unique()[0:50]
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2018-01-01')
ids = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies", header=0)[0]['Ticker symbol'].unique()

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, exchanges, ids], names=['Date', 'Exchange', 'LongID']))
```

The groupby index uses 5 seconds versus groupby columns uses 3. you could increase the size of the data frame and the difference is more meaningful.

Comment: What part did you testing on? Can you post your full code and data used?

Comment: I believe the `level` parameter for `groupby` is designed for hierarchical indices. What does the underlying dataframe look like?